# Kendo UI Client Template Not Working

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Below is the code that I am using in a modal Box, I am able to see data, but Clienttemplate which will be conditional based is not getting applied.

`@(Html.Kendo().Grid<DrillThruData>
                                          (@Model.SCRDrillThru.Child)
                                          .Name("childDrillThru")
                                          .Scrollable()
                                          .Columns(columns =>
                                          {
                                              columns.Bound(c => c.FDSSecurityCUSIPIdentifier).ClientTemplate("<a href='" + @Url.Action("Toggle", "Access") + "/#: ProviderId #" + "'>Toggle...</a>");
                                              columns.Bound(c => c.FDSPoolNumber);
                                              columns.Bound(c => c.FDSSecurityBalance);
                                              columns.Bound(c => c.FDSCollateralLookThroughAllocationPercent);
                                          })
                                          )`

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to get it work, here is the solutionFor those who wants to know`@(Html.Kendo().Grid<DrillThruChild>
                                      ()
                                      .Name("childDrillThru")
                                      .Scrollable()
                                      .Columns(columns =>
                                      {
                                          columns.Bound(c => c.FDSSecurityCUSIPIdentifier).ClientTemplate("# if (FDSPoolNumber == 'SCRB') { #" +
           "<a href='#= FDSSecurityCUSIPIdentifier #'>#= FDSSecurityCUSIPIdentifier #</a>" +
       "# } else { #" +
           "<a id ='cusipLink' href='\\#' onclick = 'return showDifferenceIssuerLink()' >#= FDSSecurityCUSIPIdentifier #</a>" +
       "# } #"); columns.Bound(c => c.FDSPoolNumber);
                                          columns.Bound(c => c.FDSSecurityBalance);
                                          columns.Bound(c => c.FDSCollateralLookThroughAllocationPercent);
                                      })`

And yes you can't dynamically create Kendo Grid using Model and then apply Client Template. I have to use ajax call.

If you need, drop a pm to me and will share whole solution.